# Storing default options in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I'm getting an error when trying to access stored option variables for the first time after installation, both in content scripts and in a service worker: `Uncaught (in promise) undefined`

Here is the code that manages user options:

```js
function save_options() {
  var mykeySetting = document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    mykey: mykeySetting
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}


function restore_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    mykey: true
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = items.mykey;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('onInstalled', restore_options);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('onInstalled', save_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My add-on</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="options.css" />

<body>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">
  Option 1
</label>

  <div id="status"></div>

  <br>

  <button id="save">Save</button>

  <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

After I hit save button in the options dialogue the errors go away, **even if I reload the extension**. In other words, the errors appear only after loading the extension for the first time, till hitting the save button.

Comment: You need to store the defaults in your background script using chrome.runtime.onInstalled event.

Comment: Doing that in the options dialogue which is registered in the manifest has no effect?

Comment: Users won't open it or they will open it after opening another page where your content script runs.

Comment: Oh, OK... I thought that listeners with `onInstalled` were getting executed during installation anyway, not when opening the respective files.

Comment: Is there a way to call the function from the options.js file in the background script in the listener or do I have to copy it to that file?

Comment: I don't see you using onInstalled anywhere. You need to do it in the background script. You can create a new script with the shared function and load it in both contexts.

Comment: Check in the bottom of my javascript code I shared. I'm using onInstalled, but that's in the options javascript file.
I'll do it the way you proposed with a shared file and I will call the function from both my background and options script.

Comment: You're not using onInstalled. You must use chrome.runtime.onInstalled, not a DOM event.

Comment: You are right. I changed that, but of course with no effect, so i will try to make the call in the background script.

Comment: OK. I added this code in my background script:

`chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        mykey: true
    });
});`

It solves the problem for the content scripts, but still I get an error from the background script itself, where I also check the same option variable. Is there a way to secure that the execution of that code will run before any other code in my background script?

Comment: Simply don't check the variable in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxom
I need to make changes also in the background script based on the users preferences.
There must be a way.

Comment: I can't help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240463/discussion-between-costas-and-woxxom).

Comment: I have added the code in chat, because of its length.